# Passing variable from one form to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've looked this question up 10 times but each answer is too specific to the question.

I have two public classes, one per form.

The first form has a textbox and two buttons:

```
Public Class frmAdd
    Public addvar As String
    Public Sub UltraButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles btnAddNote.Click

        If txtAdd.Text = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please complete the notes textbox!")
        Else
            addvar = txtAdd.Text
            MsgBox(addvar)
            Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub UltraButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the second form I want to take that addvar variable and say

```
Public Sub saveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click

    frmAdd.show()

    me.textbox1.text = addvar
```

How do I get this to work in vb.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read the field out of the `frmAdd` value

```
Me.textbox1.Text = frmAdd.addvar
```

Note that this value won't be available until the form has completed, and is closed (`Me.close`).  Hence you want to use `ShowDialog` (doesn't return until form is closed) vs. `Show` (which returns immediately after displaying the form).

```
frmAdd.ShowDialog()
Me.textbox1.Text = frmAdd.addvar
```