# Trying to pass value through forms, but not working correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Dim form As New Mainuser(TextBox1.Text)
```

For some reason, even though `TextBox1` exists, it still says it's not declared.

Also, in my other part of the code, `Mainuser.Show()`, it says can not be simplified. Here is my full code if you want to help me with that:

Login.vb:

```
Dim form As New Mainuser(TextBox1.Text)
If TextBox8.Text = My.Settings.username AndAlso TextBox9.Text = My.Settings.password Then
    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully been logged in!", "Login Successfull")
    Close()
    Mainuser.Show()
```

Mainuser.vb:

```
Public Class Mainuser
    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)

        InitializeComponent()

        Label1.Text = value

    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        HTML_Editor.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Like I said before if this doesn't make any sense I'll comment below what you want.

Oh yeah, here are my error messages:

1. (BC30451) `TextBox1` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
2. (BC30469) Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: Can you show the actual error types and error messages?  Also, simply using @Bugs doesn't mean that user will get notified.  And if you  need to clarify, don't do it in the comments here -- update the question itself.

Comment: Pretty likely that `TextBox1` exists in a different form than the one you're trying to use it from. It is unclear what relevance the other code you've shown has to anything being asked here. `TextBox1` never appears there. You should be preparing a [MCVE]. Or, better yet, just start reading any of the hundreds of questions here about accessing objects on another form.

Comment: Sigh. I fixed your code formatting once, but I see you've clobbered it by adding in the error message. Please fix the code formatting back. It isn't that hard to indent by 4 spaces. There's even a button on the toolbar that will do it for you, or you can press Ctrl+K. Maybe it would have been smart to read the help before starting to ask questions?

Comment: `TextBox1.Text` has to be on the form you want to use it on. Not the form you want to pass the value to. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: In fact instead of using `TextBox1.Text` _I think_ you want to use `TextBox8.Text`...`Dim form As New Mainuser(TextBox8.Text)` since that is the username you are comparing with

Comment: Also please don't ask a new question. Instead you should have edited your other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass value from Form1 to Form2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903216/how-to-pass-value-from-form1-to-form2)

Comment: @Bugs at least the other guy had declared his TextBox

Comment: @djv yes that certainly helps.

Comment: @Bugs it works but my `Mainuser.Show()`, still gives me an error.

Comment: @Zualux what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This errors can be avoided easily with a `module`. You can create one by right-clicking on your solution -> Add -> Module.

After that just declare your variables, take this as an example.

```
Public _stringname As String
Public _decimalname As Decimal
Public _numbername As Integer
Public _doublename As Double
```

After that, you just call whenever you want it. For example, you have a textbox on form1 that you want to pass the value to form2:

**Form1 button click event:**
_stringname = txtYourTextBox.Text
_decimalname = txtYourMaskedTextBox.Text

**Form2 Load event:**
lblYourStringLabel.Text = _stringname
lblYourDecimalLabel.Text = _decimal

And so on...

Hope this helps.